Can I partition my data drive so only one OS can access each partition?
I'm about to begin with my first PC build and I'm trying to plan how I'll organise my storage. My Plan is two SSD's: one for the OS and one for data. I want to have the OS drive partitioned for windows and Ubuntu which I know I can do quite easily. I'm mostly curious about partitioning my data drive so one part is only accessed by the linux OS and the other part is only accessed by the windows OS.
It's my first time doing this so maybe it's a silly question and I'm over thinking but I don't want all of the data drive to be accessed by each OS, only the data that is applicable to that OS. If my explanation doesn't make sense, I've attached a graphic that hopefully helps.

If anyone can help or has any tips I'd really appreciate it!

Windows by default can not see EXT4, the Ubuntu default. Or you do it with security permissions.. Research permissions.

At the very least, with sudo permissions and the appropriate NTFS packages installed, an Ubuntu machine can mount a Windows machine and its files.  Of course, you can make sure it is not listed in the /etc/fstab file so that it isn't mounted automatically.  But there's nothing you can do to prevent an administrator from mounting it...which requires you to enter the administrator's password.  You just have to remember not to do it, if you are worried about it?

You can set up in the Windows side to encrypt the data drive with bitlocker for the Windows component if you have the proper licensing.  In Linux, you can make the 'data drive' an LVM2 member and make it a logical drive inside that, then it can't be read by Windows.  However, both are nontrivial to set up and the Windows side is offtopic here.  Additionally, bitlocker encryption on the drives will affect the ability to dualboot, so you really need to consider carefully your options here.

@user535733 Sorry if my question was worded poorly. I'm not looking for someone to give me a step-by-step, I'm just new to it and I would like to learn, I just don't know where to start! Google searches kept returning results that didn't really apply to what I was trying to do so I'm really just looking for a nudge in the right direction

This question is similar to: How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In David DE's comment, he stated how Windows by default doesn't read the EXT4 file system format that Ubuntu uses, so my Ubuntu data and projects will be hidden from windows, which is what I need.
To hide my Windows data and projects from Ubuntu, I found this page where the accepted answer also answers my question:
How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu

Mind that it is always possible to delete and format a partition. You can not prevent that. Hiding a partition might give the assumption there is nothing there and someone might see that as a good idea to format it and start using it
